# Disconnected Azure VM from internet by disabling the ethernet

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

Disconnected Azure VM from internet by disabling the Ethernet. How can I enable internet connection again by enabling the Ethernet.

Comment: Please be more precise about what actions you took.

Answer (score 1):

Change the size of the VM. This will de-allocate and re-allocate the VM and will result in the NIC being re-enabled. You can change it back to the original size after.

Comment: or select VM >> redeploy. This will work the same way by moving the VM to a new hardware cluster, hence, resetting network settings.

Answer (score -1):

According to your description, I have tested resize VM size and redeploy the VM, but the VM still disconnected. It seems that there is no way direct to enable the Ethernet, we can recreate the VM with the OS disk.
In ASM mode, use the portal to delete the VM and “keep the attached disks”, and create a new VM with the attached disks. In the ARM mode, use the portal to delete the VM, and the OS disk will be saved automatic, and we can create the VM with PowerShell.
$rgname = "your resourcename"
$loc = "location"
$vmsize = "Standard_DS1_v2"
$vmname = "vmname"
$vm = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $vmname -VMSize $vmsize
$nic = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name ("name of nic") -ResourceGroupName   $rgname
$nicId = $nic.Id
$vm = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vm -Id $nicId
$osDiskName = "disk name"
$osDiskVhdUri = "https://yourOSsidk.vhd"
$vm = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $vm -VhdUri $osDiskVhdUri -name $osDiskName -CreateOption attach -Windows
New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Location $loc -VM $vm

If you still have questions, welcome to post back here. Thanks.
Best Regards,